# how to find $\inf$ and $\sup$ of this set?

Tags: calculus, elementary-set-theory

What is $\inf\{t>0  \,x\in\mathbb{R}$ $:t\ge1+x,t\ge 1-x\}$ how can I visualize ? And for the sup?

Comment: What is $x$? A pink bycicle? A cyan shirt? Me, perhaps?

Comment: @ajotatxe modified, x is in R

Comment: I have no idea what that set is supposed to be. Perhaps that you are taking an arbitrary real number $x$ and you're after $\inf\{t>0\mid t\geqslant1+x\wedge t\geqslant1-x\}$. Is that it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visualize it drawing the two lines $t=1+x$ and $t=1-x$; for $t$ being greater or equal than both $1-x$ and $1+x$ means that it is greater or equal than the maximum of these two functions.

For understanding when you have to pick one function or the other, you have to understand when $1+x\geq 1-x$ and when $1-x \geq 1+x$:

$$1+x \geq 1-x \ \iff \ 2x \geq 0 \ \iff \ x \geq 0 \ \ ,$$
while
$$ 1-x \geq 1+x \ \iff \ -2x \geq 0 \ \iff \ x \leq 0 \ \ ,$$
so you have to consider the function 1+x for $x \geq 0$ and the function $1-x$ for $x \leq 0$. In particular, this "combo" function, i.e. the max of these two functions, is equal to $1+|x|$.

So, the $\inf_{t>0} \{ {t\geq 1+|x|} \ | \ x \in \mathbb{R} \} = \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}}{(1+|x|)}$, which is 1, when $x=0$. For the sup, it's the same and it is $+ \infty$ because $1+|x|$ is superiorly unbounded.

In particular, the condition $t>0$ is trivially satisfied because the function $1+|x|$ is $>0 \ \forall \ x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: really thanks , very clear explanation

Comment: @SilvioM : $\forall x\in \Bbb R, \inf_{t>0} \{ {t\geq 1+|x|}  \} =1+|x|$. Is not it ?

Comment: I believe OP's envisioned set is still unclear and we're still wondering about the color of @ajotatxe's shirt :)